# Can the exponential distribution actually be used to model light bulbs lifetime?

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, application

In my textbook they use the lifetimes of lightbulbs (or other mechanical failures) as an example for an application of the exponential distribution.

Can/is this actually done in real life? The reason of my doubt is that the exponential distribution has the memoryless property, meaning that

$$ P(X \geq t + h \ | \ X \geq t) = P(X \geq h) $$

But for lightbulbs (or mechanical failures), because of physical considerations like wear and tear, consecutive expansion/contraction of the wire when turning the light bulb on/off, and so on, the probability *does* change if you start observing after a time $t$, meaning

$$ P(X \geq t + h \ | X \geq t) < P(X \geq h) $$

So that the exponential distribution isn't a valid model? Or is the difference so low that it can be ignored?

Comment: Meeker and Escobar, *Statistical Methods for Reliability Data*, contains lots of real data in its examples.  Much of this book appears to be available on Google Books: search for it.

Comment: [a list of post about memoryless property with answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=memoryless++answers%3A1).